# Whats the IP that gives connect timed out in GoogleCredential token request?

Tags: java, proxy, google-api, token, google-oauth

I'm using GoogleCredential to try to get a token in order to call a Google API as you can see at the end of my question. If I execute the code in my personal WiFi it works perfectly but if I do it at my workplace LAN it gives me a

> "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out" error.

I'm behind a proxy but I've set up the VM proxy variables (`-Dhttps.proxyHost, -Dhttp.proxyHost, -Dhttps.proxyPort, etc`). I'm thinking that the error may be that the connection I'm trying to do is somehow blocked by the proxy.

Does anyone know which IP could I try to ping in order to tell the system admin that I can not arrive to that ip address?

```
NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("CredentialInformation.json");
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(resource.getInputStream(), httpTransport, jsonFactory)
        .createScoped(Collections.singleton(env.getProperty("google.cloud.printing.scope")));
credential.refreshToken();
String token = credential.getAccessToken();
```

Comment: start with trying to contact the auth servers. https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth

Comment: @DaImTo if I open that address on my browser it gives me `error 400: bad request` but the error page loads well.

Comment: I found a huge list about a month ago for a similar question on stack.   There was like 50+ servers.  Trying to remember where i found the list

Comment: @DaImTo thanks a lot